# Rpy2, convert a R return (List Vector) to a Json object in Python

Tags: python, json, r, flask, rpy2

I have an web application where a module use the tool **rpy2**, this with the purpose to call and execute R-scripts(because I want increase app modularity) inside a python code.

My application is have a client-server arquitecture and the communication between them is throught HTTP requests. The tool that I have to achive this was **Flask**.

Now, I have a R-script that its task is execute a clustering proccess and return a data frame converted in a **JSON** format, for this I used jsonlite, in R. My problem begin here. The problem is that the return of this R-script inside the python code is a ListVector.

I don't know but in this format python gets the R-script result. So really I don't know how convert this result (ListVector) in a JSON object, from python, because finally I need return JSON object in the service that I want expose. I try to understand the rpy2 documentation but is not clear for me [rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_convert.html).

R-Script

```
require(kohonen)
require(jsonlite)

group = read.csv2("/home/python_user/Documents/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/resources/data2.csv", header = T, sep = ",", fill = F)
group$X <- NULL

data_train <- group[, -c(3:8)]

### 
data_train <- data_train[data_train$NumeroAdultos != 12094,]

data_train$lat <- as.numeric(as.character(data_train$lat))
data_train$lon <- as.numeric(as.character(data_train$lon))
str(data_train)

#### Write JSON K-means #######

cl <- kmeans(data_train, 5)
cl$cluster
result <- data_train[,1:2]
result <- cbind(result, colorCluster = cl$cluster)
result$colorCluster[result$colorCluster == 1] <- "red"
result$colorCluster[result$colorCluster == 2] <- "blue"
result$colorCluster[result$colorCluster == 3] <- "green"
result$colorCluster[result$colorCluster == 4] <- "orange"
result$colorCluster[result$colorCluster == 5] <- "yellow"

toJSON(result, pretty = TRUE)
```

Main.py

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, jsonify, send_from_directory, render_template, Blueprint, request
import json
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

@map_module.route("/serviceData")
def service_data():
    r = robjects.r
    result = r.source(map_module.root_path + "/R/clustering.R")
    return result
```

Console Result

```
File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/home/python_user/Documentos/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'ListVector' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2017 17:32:36] "GET /serviceData HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The below line show the "result" variable that store the return of R-script, the value of this variable when call the R-script is a ListVector and don't a JSON object.

```
result = r.source(map_module.root_path + "/R/clustering.R")
```

Thanks for read me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been try resolve this problem and I found a solution that for me is not the best. So the solution is, from R-script, return the JSON object, get with python and load as a list (python object) with the library JSON and the service json.load. Once done this you have an python object (as list but the JSON structure), so finally convert this list in JSON object in python. Remember the problem was that the R-sript return a ListVector in python and this object does not callable inside python.

**Final Result**

R-Sript (I corrected some things but the essence or structure is the same)

```
# K-means Clustering 
require(jsonlite)

# Read the data
group = read.csv2("/home/python_user/Documents/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/resources/data2.csv", header = T, sep = ",", fill = F)

# Prepare the data
group$X <- NULL
group <- group[, -c(3:8)]
group <- group[group$NumeroAdultos != 12094,]
group$lat <- as.numeric(as.character(group$lat))
group$lon <- as.numeric(as.character(group$lon))

# Excute the K-means algorithm
cl <- kmeans(group[,3:9], 5)

# Bind the data with its number cluster
group <- group[,1:2]
group <- cbind(group, colorCluster = cl$cluster)

# Change conventions 
group$colorCluster[group$colorCluster == 1] <- "red"
group$colorCluster[group$colorCluster == 2] <- "blue"
group$colorCluster[group$colorCluster == 3] <- "green"
group$colorCluster[group$colorCluster == 4] <- "orange"
group$colorCluster[group$colorCluster == 5] <- "yellow"

# Convert the data frame to JSON object
toJSON(group, pretty=FALSE)
```

Main.py

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, jsonify, send_from_directory, render_template, Blueprint, request
import json
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

@map_module.route("/getEntomoClustering", methods=['GET'])
def clustering():
    r = robjects.r
    dataR = r.source(map_module.root_path + "/R/clustering.R")[0][0]
    clusters = json.loads(dataR)
    return jsonify(clusters)
```

Console Result

```
[
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.8946, 
    "lon": -76.2884
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.8988, 
    "lon": -76.2904
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.9008, 
    "lon": -76.2904
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.9034, 
    "lon": -76.2916
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.8934, 
    "lon": -76.2916
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.9067, 
    "lon": -76.2941
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.8972, 
    "lon": -76.2947
  }, 
  {
    "colorCluster": "red", 
    "lat": 3.8948, 
    "lon": -76.2964
  },... ]
```

To take into account, the result of R-script is a ListVector, inside of this it find the data Json that was convert with R, but in python is not a callable object. For this I access until this data JSON and I know that have the JSON structure, so I use the service json.load and get a list (python object) to finally convert again in a JSON object with the service jsonify (this object can be treated with python object, callable)

```
dataR = r.source(map_module.root_path + "/R/clustering.R")[0][0] //JSON data from R is not callable
    clusters = json.loads(dataR) // load a list, python object
    return jsonify(clusters) // convert to JSON object callable
```

Any questions for this solution ask me.
Thanks for read.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the R dataframe to a pandas dataframe; from there it's easier to convert that to a json format.

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

iris_r = robjects.r("data(iris);iris")

iris_pd = pandas2ri.ri2py(iris_r)
```